# How do I solve this Java question of printing a table using a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, pow

(Print a table) Write a program that displays the following table. Cast floating point numbers into integers.

```
a b pow(a, b)
1 2 1
2 3 8
3 4 81
4 5 1024
5 6 15625
```

I am having trouble conceptualizing how I can make this code simpler using loops.

```
public class Exercise_02_eighteen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a, b;
        System.out.println("a        b        pow(a, b)");
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        System.out.println((int)a + "        " + (int)b + 
            "        " + (int)Math.pow(a, b));
        a++;
        b++;
        System.out.println((int)a + "        " + (int)b + 
            "        " + (int)Math.pow(a, b));
        a++;
        b++;
        System.out.println((int)a + "        " + (int)b + 
            "        " + (int)Math.pow(a, b));
        a++;
        b++;
        System.out.println((int)a + "        " + (int)b + 
            "        " + (int)Math.pow(a, b));
        a++;
        b++;
        System.out.println((int)a + "        " + (int)b + 
            "        " + (int)Math.pow(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `for(int a = 1, b = 2, i = 0; i < 5; a++, b++, i++) { System.out.println((int)a + "        " + (int)b + "        " + (int)Math.pow(a, b)); }`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over **a** (notice it just varies from 1 to 5) and for each **a**, **b** is **a + 1**

Answer (score 1):

Just move your print under for loop:

```
public class Exercise_02_eighteen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("a\tb\tpow(a, b)");

        for (int a = 1, b = 2; a <= 5; a++, b++)
            System.out.format("%d\t%d\t%d\n", a, b, (long)Math.pow(a, b));
    }

}
```

Comment: I would use a different variable for indexing the number of loops.

Comment: You do not need two variables to do it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash this is true. I find it more clear than your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Exercise_02_eighteen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("a        b        pow(a, b)");

        for(int a = 1, b = 2, i = 0; i < 5; a++, b++, i++) { // <--
            System.out.println((int)a + " " + (int)b + " " + (int)Math.pow(a, b)); // <--
        } // <--
    }
}
```

Comment: Why so many variables? :) You could have used just one variable.

Comment: To keep separate concepts separate, I believe. But yes, you can technically combine them if you want, this is just a simple exercise, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code will help you, there are so many approaches but your question is very basic so I just show use of loop in your program.

```
   public class Exercise_02_eighteen {


     public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a, b, numberOfRows = 5;
        System.out.println("a\tb\tpow(a, b)");
        //removed unused space and use \t : tab
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        for(int i=1; i< numberOfRows; i++)
        {
                System.out.println((int)a + "\t" + (int)b + "\t" + (int)Math.pow(a, b));
                a++;
                b++;
        }

    }

}
```

If you want to write for the same series you show in question then you may write code without extra variables, like below or may be take one variable if required.

```
public class Exercise_02_eighteen {


     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, numberOfRows = 5;
        System.out.println("a\tb\tpow(a, b)");
        //removed unused space and use \t : tab
        for(i=1; i< numberOfRows; i++)
        {
                System.out.println((int)i + "\t" + (int)(i+1) + "\t" + (int)Math.pow(i, i+1));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You do not need two variables to do it.

Comment: I know, I just made change to help him understand.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two variables. You can do it using a single variable as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("a\tb\tpow(a, b)");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + (i + 1) + "\t" + (int) Math.pow(i, i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a   b   pow(a, b)
1   2   1
2   3   8
3   4   81
4   5   1024
5   6   15625
```